# Arrange the digits from 0 to 9 into a number which is divisible by every integer from 12 to 21

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

Arrange the digits from 0 to 9 into a number which is divisible by every integer from 12 to 21 inclusive.

(There are 2 right answers.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numbers are

> 2137458960 and 6179584320

I found these results by calculating the least common multiple $\operatorname{lcm}(12,\dotsc 21) = 21162960$, then checking all multiples of this value up to 9876543210 with a script: https://jsfiddle.net/qdnyLfx8/

There must be more elegant solutions that work without using a computer.

Comment: Well then I won't post the 2nd number.

Comment: The prime factors of 12 to 21 are 24×3×5×7×13×17×19, therefore the two 10-digit pandigital numbers are a multiple of 7054320.       2137458960 [7054320×303] and 6179584320 [7054320×876].

Comment: @JamalSenjaya Based on GOTO 0's LCM calculation you seem to have missed a factor of 3 somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

If I take all the factors of 12-21 and multiply them together, I get

> 5 * 7 * 9 * 13 * 16 * 17 * 19, or
>  21162960

So now all that is left to do is to keep adding it to itself until I get a 10 digit number that satisfies the requirements. The first such number is

> 2137458960